# ssis package for checking condition by other table's value

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have query like-

```
select work_Id, startdate,work_per from Work a
where work_per is not null
and StartDate = (select max(StartDate) from Work b where a.work_Id=b.work_Id)
```

i want to create a package in ssis for this query..
i am face problem in giving condition.in

```
select max(StartDate) from Work b where a.work_Id=b.work_Id.
```

here i am checking column `a.work_Id's` values to `b.work_Id`.
i really don't know how can i check it in ssis. i tried with condition split but it filter only one table's value only.
and i dont want to use any query in package.. plz give some suggestions..

Comment: Try using Lookup transform. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: i tried with lookup. but didn't get result. may be i was wrong in that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MERGE JOIN transformation to achieve this. It will have two inputs.

1) `select work_Id, startdate,work_per from Work a where work_per is not null`

2) `select work_Id,max(StartDate) as StartDate from Work b group by b.work_Id`

These two inputs will be joined in MERGE JOIN on Work_ID and Start_Date.
Hope this will help..!!

Thanks,
Swapnil